# ComboBoxItem not clearing unknown value on blur

Tags: smartclient

To Start, here is my ComboBoxItem field

```
{
    name: "State",
    type: "ComboBoxItem",
    canEdit: true,
    valueMap: {
        WI: "Wisconsin",
        IL: "Illinois",
        MN: "Minnesota",
        MI: "Michigan"
    },
    addUnknownValues: false,
    allowEmptyValue: false,
    completeOnTab: true
}
```

I'm getting very different behavior out of a `ComboBoxItem` when it is in a `ListGrid` vs when it's in a `DynamicForm`.

In a DynamicForm if you were to type in a value that does NOT have a match in the valueMap and then leave the field, it would return to the previous value.

In an editable ListGrid if you were to type in a value that does NOT have a match in the valueMap and then leave the field, it would keep what ever characters you typed and try to save the edits with that string.

[Walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1qGOKM6OYI)

The code used in the walkthrough

```
isc.VLayout.create({
    height: 500,
    width: 900,
    margin: 100,
    members: [
        isc.ListGrid.create({
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            canEdit: true,
            modalEditing: true,
            extraSpace: 5,
            fields: [
                { name: "Name", canEdit: true, },
                {
                    name: "State",
                    type: "ComboBoxItem",
                    canEdit: true,
                    valueMap: {
                        WI: "Wisconsin",
                        IL: "Illinois",
                        MN: "Minnesota",
                        MI: "Michigan"
                    },
                    addUnknownValues: false,
                    //allowEmptyValue: false,
                    completeOnTab: true
                }
            ],
            data: [
                { Name: "Evan", State: "WI" },
                { Name: "Erik", State: "IL" },
                { Name: "Philip", State: "MI" },
            ]
        }),
        isc.DynamicForm.create({
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            border: "1px solid #ababab",
            canEdit: true,
            fields: [
                { name: "Name", canEdit: true, },
                {
                    name: "State",
                    type: "ComboBoxItem",
                    canEdit: true,
                    valueMap: {
                        WI: "Wisconsin",
                        IL: "Illinois",
                        MN: "Minnesota",
                        MI: "Michigan"
                    },
                    addUnknownValues: false,
                    allowEmptyValue: false,
                    completeOnTab: true
                }
            ],
            values: { Name: "Evan", State: "WI" }
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that `addUnknownValues` has a different effect on the two instances.

I solved the issue by moving `addUnknownValues` to the ListGridField's `editorProperties`

this is the updated ListGridField item

```
{
    name: "State",
    type: "ComboBoxItem",
    canEdit: true,
    valueMap: {
        WI: "Wisconsin",
        IL: "Illinois",
        MN: "Minnesota",
        MI: "Michigan"
    },
    editorProperties:{
        addUnknownValues: false,
        allowEmptyValue: false,
        completeOnTab: true
    }
}
```

Comment: correct, editorProperties is the right way to pass attributes to the DynamicForm which is used for editing of the grid record.